# TIBCO-EMS: Set message delay based on JMS message header

Tags: java, jms, tibco-ems

I need different delay for different messages based on special conditions. Is there a way to set the delivery delay in a message header using TIBCO EMS like in ActiveMQ?

[ActiveMQ example](https://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery):

```java
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("test msg");
    
if (condition) {
   long time = 60 * 1000;
   message.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, time);
}
producer.send(message);
```

Comment: Does Tibco EMS support JMS 2?

Comment: What version of Tibco EMS are you using?

Comment: Tibco EMS 8.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Tibco EMS supports JMS 2 then you can use [`javax.jms.MessageProducer#setDeliveryDelay(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#setDeliveryDelay-long-):

```
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("test msg");
    
if (condition) {
   long time = 60 * 1000;
   producer.setDeliveryDelay(time);
}
producer.send(message);
```

Comment: TIBCO EMS 8.X support JMS 2.0 specification